# Which frameworks can be used in Watch Kit2 application

Tags: ios, cocoa, import, watchkit, apple-watch

Is there anyone could tell me where can I find official place that lists all of frameworks can be used in WatchKit2 application?

So far, what I know is UIKit, CoreTelephony are not able to be imported in watch kit 2 classes.
CoreLocation, Foundation are able to be imported.

How about AVFoundation, ClockKit, CloudKit, Contacts, CoreAudio, CoreData, CoreFoundation, CoreGraphics, ... and alots

Answer (score 0):

Please view the watchOS release notes in the Apple Developer portal.

[Apple watchOS API diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInwatchOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016634)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured out how to manually check for all classes existence in any SDK.

Open any SDK header. For example: `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`

Look up at the editor's header path. Here there is `Simulator - iOS 10.2 > Frameworks > UIKit > UIKit.h`
Click on `Simulator - iOS 10.2`, select `watch OS 3.1 >` to expand and acknowledge what is there.

I also know that watch OS SDK also has its own `UIKit`, `UIFont` frameworks, but they are much more smaller than iSO SDK.
Let take a look at `UIKit` under `watch OS 3.1` and you will see.

Hope this will help people